# t-day covariance matrix from daily return data

Tags: time-series, covariance, lognormal-distribution, finance

How do I get t-day covariance matrix from daily return data?

I have an idea of how to calculate t-day variance from daily return data. From 14.6, 14.7 in *Options, Futures and Other Derivatives* by John Hull, I know that assuming stock price follows Ito's process, t-day log return follows a normal distribution and its expected value and variance are just those of daily log return scaled by t. Based on these and the properties of lognormal distributions, I can do the following step:

1. compute daily log return from daily return
2. compute the expected value and variance of daily log return
   $$\operatorname{E}[\log r_d] = \mu$$
   $$\operatorname{var}(\log r_d) = \sigma^2$$
3. compute the expected value and variance of t-day log return by scaling daily values by t
   $$\operatorname{E}[r_t] = \mu t$$
   $$\operatorname{var}(\log r_t) = \sigma^2t$$
4. compute the expected value and variance of return by the property of log normal distributions
   $$\operatorname{E}[r_t] = \exp(\mu t + \frac{\sigma^2}{2})$$
   $$\operatorname{var}(r_t) =  [\exp(\sigma^{2})-1]\exp(2\mu +\sigma ^{2})$$

If the above are valid, what are the similar reasonings for covariance matrix if I am looking at more than a single stock?

I see in practice some people seem to just scale covariance by 252 when calculating annualized covariance. Also, they don't seem to handle the difference of return and log return. But I don't understand why.

(I can't find appropriate tags for this question)

Answer (score 2):

Let $M_d$ be the covariance matrix for the daily log-values.

Then $M_t = t M_d$ is the covariance matrix for the log-values after $t$ days.

From this, standard formulas give the covariances of the values, as in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132855/expectation-variance-and-correlation-of-a-bivariate-lognormal-distribution).

One way to write those formulas is that if $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal, then
$$\text{Cov}[e^X,e^Y]\, =E[e^X]\: E[e^Y]\:(e^{\text{Cov}(X,Y)}-1)$$

Comment: But I already know people scale up the log of daily covariance, what I don't understand is why this is valid. For variance,  John Hull gave the reasoning starting from the assumption that stock price follows Ito's process. I want similar reasoning for covariance.

Comment: If you want to know reasoning that’s parallel to Hull’s argument about variance, then it makes sense to post a new question which includes or summarizes or paraphrases that argument, and ask for the analog with covariance there.